# responsive navbar stacking insted of scaling

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a copy of this website:http://www.granngarden.se for school, but I am having problems getting the navmenu to scale down when I resize the browser window. Here is a CodePen link to the full code;  `http://codepen.io/Nealc/pen/gPNZrj?editors=1100`

I think the problem is with the container because if I remove the blocks on the side the menu is still stacking instead of scaling down.

HTML:

```
<nav>
          <div class="sideBlock meny" id="leftBlock"></div>
               <div class="container">
                   <ul class="meny">
                       <li class="leftMeny"><a href="">Lantbruk & Skog</a></li>
                       <li class="leftMeny"><a href="">Trädgård</a></li>
                       <li class="leftMeny"><a href="">Djur & Foder</a></li>
                       <li class="leftMeny"><a href="">Kläder & Skor</a></li>
                       <li class="leftMeny"><a href="">Hus & Hem</a></li>
                       <li class="leftMeny"><a href="">Lagerfynd</a></li>
                   </ul>
                   <div class="block meny"></div>
                   <ul class="meny">
                       <li class="rightMeny"><a href="">kundklubb</a></li>
                       <li class="rightMeny"><a href="">kundtjänst</a></li>
                       <li class="rightMeny"><a href="">grannliv</a></li>
                   </ul>

               </div>
           <div class="sideBlock meny" id="rightBlock"></div>

       </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 65%;
}
nav{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.meny{
    float: left;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 55px;

}
.meny li{
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #801f1f;
    list-style: none;
    height: 18px;
    font-size: 95%;
    float: left;
    max-width: 29%;
}
.rightMeny{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.block{
    width: 15%;
    height: 36px;
    background: #801f1f;
    margin-top: 56px;

}
.sideBlock{
    width: 17.5%;
    height: 36px;
    background: #801f1f;
    margin-top: 56px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

They're using scale classes, you can check out one of the most popular examples on bootstrap http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#quick-start-example

I'm not sure if you had this in mind, but if you did you can check out Variables, Mixins and Example usage chapters in the link.

Comment: No this was not what I was looking for. Thanks for your comment